# Leaflet add data to GeoJSON without showing on map

Tags: leaflet

I am adding using GeoJSON data pulled from a service. I want to load the GeoJSON layer but I don't want to display the data on map.
This code is adding myLayer with the default blue color to the map.  Why is my layer added to the map even if I have not called `myLayer.addTo(map)`? I just want to use it as source data for a search function, not to display them on the map.

```
fetch('url')
.then(function(response) {
    return response.text();
  })
  .then(function(res) {
    return JSON.parse(res)
  })
  .then(function(res){
    myLayer= new L.geoJSON(res);
  })
```

Comment: Please provide a minimal runnable example that reproduces the error, for example with https://jsfiddle.net/ or codepen.io. Alternatively post the code here. Its very hard to say without more code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have a minimal working example at https://codepen.io/anon/pen/MxaEOW that does what you want without error.

The relevant code part is

```
var map = new L.Map('map').setView([ 52, 9 ], 4);
....
var myLayer; // just create the global variable, no assignment yet!


document.getElementById("fetch").addEventListener("click",
  function() {

    fetch("https://gist.githubusercontent.com/anonymous/e54a23c4d5204d7ea8c1/raw/a9559d405c30630caccc4a59c26e20a2d44f3d6e/map.geojson")
    .then(function(response) {
      return response.text();
    })
    .then(function(res) {
      return JSON.parse(res)
    })
    .then(function(res){
      // assign to global variable. Don't add yet!
      myLayer= new L.geoJSON(res);
      // display feature count, for debugging purposes (returns 6 features)
      document.getElementById("r").innerHTML = Object.keys(myLayer._layers).length + " features"
    })
  }
);

document.getElementById("addmylayer").addEventListener("click",
  function() {
    // add myLayer to map here. myLayer is global, so can be used.
    myLayer.addTo(map);
  });
```

This works, so probably you already added the layer somewhere in your code, either by calling  `myLayer.addTo(map)` or by specifying the layer in the map constructor (thanks @TomazicM , see comment)!

Comment: Thanks for your example, really neat! I must look again at my code where it might be added on the map. It's quite small application so I am surprised that I might have missed it. Will be out for a couple of days but will go and have a look and compare

Comment: Layer can also be added when defining map, for example: `var map = L.map('map', {center: [52, 9], zoom: 4, layers: [myLayer] });`